# Infinite loop when byte compile

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm author of [evil-commentary](https://github.com/linktohack/evil-commentary), the full source less than 200 lines can be found in the repo.

Basically I have something like this.

```
(evil-define-operator evil-commentary (beg end type)
  "Comment or uncomment region that {motion} moves over."
  :move-point nil
  (interactive "<R>")
  (let ((comment-function
         (cdr (assoc major-mode
                     evil-commentary-comment-function-for-mode-alist))))
    (if comment-function (funcall comment-function beg end)
      (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end))))


(defun evil-commentary-comment-for-org (beg end)
  "Comment function for `org-mode'."
  (interactive "r")
  (if (and (fboundp 'org-in-src-block-p)
           (org-in-src-block-p))
      (evil-commentary-do-in-org-src-block beg end
        (call-interactively 'evil-commentary))
    (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)))
```

The idea is that `evil-commentary` will call `evil-commentary-comment-for-org` in an org file, and if we're in a src block, `evil-commentary-comment-for-org` will call `evil-commentary` again in the `src-edit` buffer (which now has different `major-mode`)

The setup works just fine, however when I compile the code, I get an infinite loop `evil-commentary` -> `evil-commentary-comment-for-org` -> `evil-commentary`... with `Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size` error...

I found that it will work if I compile the code after `org` is loaded, but that not I wanted because `evil-commentary` will stop working if an user compile with an old version of `org` then upgrade it. (A flaw of `package.el`)

Thank you!

Comment: Before seeing Angus's answer, I thought you were seeing an inf-loop during byte-compilation itself.  Try to be more precise in how you describe the symptom you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in [this line](https://github.com/linktohack/evil-commentary/blob/master/evil-commentary.el#L129), which expands to:

```
  (org-babel-do-in-edit-buffer
   (call-interactively 'evil-commentary))
```

If you haven't loaded `org`, the byte compiler doesn't know `org-babel-do-in-edit-buffer` is a macro, and can't expand it. So it simply compiles a call to an (as of yet unknown) function called `org-babel-do-in-edit-buffer`.

When execution reaches that line, the function arguments are evaluated first (as in any other function call) and there you have your infinite loop.

Try requiring `org` inside an `eval-when-compile` block.

Comment: Thanks, @angus. That makes sense. I explain the reason why I don't want to require `org` is that an user will go to a problem if they're install `evil-commentary` before update `org`. I'm wondering if I can use `declare-function` and somehow declare that it's a macro instead (i.e. do not evaluate  arguments)

Comment: I don't think so. In any case, surround that call to `org-babel-do...` with an `(eval ...)`, but that's ugly. I wonder if there isn't any hook that tells Emacs to recompile your package when the other is upgraded (I don't really know much about packaging).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately we have no real solution so far. I'll stick with the `(eval ...)` way if I cannot find another solution. Thanks again!